# Copying data using memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy

I am doing a memcpy of clsf_ptr to upclsf

```
memcpy(&upclsf, &clsf_ptr, sizeof(struct classifier));
```

while debugging using gdb i checked the memory address  of upclsf
when i did print &upclsf i got

```
(gdb) p &upclsf
$1 = (struct classifier **) 0xbffff184
```

when i did print upclsf i got

```
(gdb) p upclsf
$2 = (struct classifier *) 0x2e312e31
```

which is the address here i am not able to understand, here upclsf is an instance of the structure classifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDB disagrees — `upclsf` is not a `struct classifier`, it is a pointer.  Note that the two answers have different types.  The first one (`&upclsf`) is `struct classifier **`, the second one (`upclsf`) is `struct classifier *`.  Here is the memory layout:

```
addr 0xbffff184 / upclsf: pointer to 0x2e312e31

addr 0x2e312e31 / *upclsf: (structure data)
```

You want to change your `memcpy` to:

```
memcpy(upclsf, &clsf_ptr, sizeof(struct classifier));
```

Or possibly:

```
memcpy(upclsf, clsf_ptr, sizeof(struct classifier));
```

Note that `memcpy` will wantonly destroy data and is not type-safe!  Therefore you have to be extra careful when you use it to ensure that the types you give it are correct.  I suggest defining the following function:

```
static inline void
classifier_copy(struct classifier *dest, struct classifier const *src)
{
    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(*dest));
}
```

This will catch type errors.  I make one of these for any structure I copy more than once or twice.

Comment: Indeed, there's a type mismatch. Another suggestion for the asker is to always remember to use this `_ptr` name suffix for pointers. When the names aren't clear you forget what's a pointer and what's not.